# SQL Where IF statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

/*    I am working in SQL Server Report Builder and I have a Where statement where a parameter equals to a value, check another parameter then do something, else do something else.  Below is an example:
*/

```
where 
case when @Parameter1 = 'Value' then 
    when @Parameter2 = True then
       Date >= @BegDate and
       Date <= @EndDate and
       totext(Field) = @Parameter1 and
      Field2 = 'Value2'
    Else
       totext(Field) = @Parameter1 and
        Field2 = 'Value2' 
Case when @Parameter1 = 'Value3' then
        Field3 = ToNumber(@Parameter3) and
        Field2 = 'Value2';
```

Comment: CASE is an *expression*, it returns a single scalar value, it's not a control-of-flow *statement*, you need to write youe logic using and/or criteria with appropriate parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `CASE` here, which returns a scalar value. Just use normal boolean logic

```sql
WHERE (
       (
             @Parameter1 = 'Value'
         AND @Parameter2 = 'True'
         AND Date >= @BegDate
         AND Date <= @EndDate
         AND totext(Field) = @Parameter1
         AND Field2 = 'Value2'
        )
  OR
        ( @Parameter1 = 'Value'
         AND totext(Field) = @Parameter1
         AND Field2 = 'Value2'
        )
  OR
        ( @Parameter1 = 'Value3'
         AND FIeld3 = ToNumber(@Parameter3)
         AND Field2 = 'Value2'
        )
  )
```

You can obviously simplify this by pulling some conditions to the outside of the `OR`

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite your case so that it "returns" something that you then check for. I'm not sure where exactly what your logic is because your `CASE`s are incorrectly nested so it's hard to read, but this should give you an idea

```
WHERE CASE -- first set of conditions
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 'Value'
         AND @Parameter2 = True
         AND Date >= @BegDate
         AND Date <= @EndDate
         AND totext(Field) = @Parameter1
         AND Field2 = 'Value2'
        THEN 1 -- return 1 when the first condition is met
  
        -- Second set of conditions      
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 'Value' -- but not @Parameter2 = True, that'd have been matched above
         AND totext(Field) = @Parameter1
         AND Field2 = 'Value2'
        THEN 1`
  
        -- Third set of conditions
        WHEN @Parameter1 = 'Value3'
         AND FIeld3 = ToNumber(@Parameter3)
         AND Field2 = 'Value2'
        THEN 1
        -- otherwise we're returning 0
        ELSE 0
    END = 1 -- here we're checking if the CASE returns a 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I appreciate the help!